# Render a region e.g page.sidebar_first in views-view.html.twig

Tags: views, 8, theming

Is it possible to render a region e.g `sidebar_first` in a views twig-file `views-view.html.twig`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not the region itself, but you can render the blocks with [Twig Tweak](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak), so simply add the blocks that are in that region to your template file.

> Twig Tweak module provides a Twig extension with some useful functions
>   and filters that can improve development experience.
>
> ```
> {# The block with this ID should be configured on "admin/structure/block" page. #}
>   <dt>Block:</dt>
>   <dd>{{ drupal_block('bartik_powered') }}</dd>
> ```

Comment: Yes, that's the most practicable solution, placing the blocks from the region, not the region itself.

Comment: Ok thanks. But then I don't have to add those blocks to that region? Because I don't use that region, because I am not able to render it, if I understand your answer. Is that correct?

Comment: `I don't have to add those blocks to that region?` perhaps not, as long as they are listed under Disabled, you should be able to get the block ID. So just add them to a region and then disable them.

Answer (score 2):

There is not a Drupal way to do this. Normally it's the other way, you put views in regions (via block layout). You would need to code this yourself by replicating how core fills regions with blocks:

```
$blocks = entity_load_multiple_by_properties('block', array('theme' => $theme, 'region' => $region));
// Sort ‘em
uasort($blocks, 'Drupal\block\Entity\Block::sort');
// Capture viewable blocks and their settings to $build
$build = array();
foreach ($blocks as $key => $block) {
  if ($block->access('view')) {
    $build[$key] = entity_view($block, 'block');
  }
}
// Add build to region
$variables[$region] = $build;
```

Source:

https://atendesigngroup.com/blog/making-region-content-available-node-templates-drupal-8